# WebRTC stream from gstreamer in local netwrok with lowest possible security

Tags: stream, webrtc, gstreamer, rtp, sdp

I need to connect to gstreamer multicast udp stream with WebRTC. I do not need any security, but web browsers require them. The connection is made only in local network, so no ICE, STUN or TURN servers are required. What is minimum possible configuration to connect from browser's WebRTC to any rtp video stream?

I have this gstreamer pipelin (if it'd help):

`gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! rtph264pay mtu=1400 config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=239.127.1.21 multicast-iface=192.168.137.83 port=5000`

And this SDP file which works with VLC to play the stream:

```
v=0
o=- 1 0 IN IP4 192.168.137.1
s=-
c=IN IP4 239.127.1.21
t=0 0
a=sendonly
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96
a=sendonly
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

If I use the SDP in a browser, of course there is problem that I don't set some ICE stuff, but i really don't need them and I have no idea on how to generate them. I would rather ignore whole ICE thing and just tell browser to use some different sort of security if it is possible.

So how can I play the stream in a browser?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you need simplest WebRTC configuration - you will need full implementation. I.e. some signaling protocol, and ICE candidate negotiation, and streams encryption. The only difference - you will always use local ICE candidates, without use STUN or TURN - it's still possible.
And I think you will have to use [webrtcbin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c).

Comment: Okay, so how can I implement ICE negotiation? I cannot find any useful documentation on how to generate ICE attributes. They are either totally low level or use only browser API.

Comment: I think it's better use some ready to use implementation, something like libnice (https://nice.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

Comment: Other way could be use Janus gateway, since it's already have all signalling and ICE related stuff, in conjunction my GStreamer plugin (https://github.com/RSATom/janus-gstreamer-plugin). Right now I'm trying to go this way in one of my project, but I'm still in the middle of path, and can't be sure it's 100% right choice.

Comment: I would prefer to implement custom signaling. So if you know any usable docs please recommend.

Comment: Signalling is pretty simple task I think, there are many examples over internet, but ICE negotiation could be much harder to implement, especially if do it from scratch. Maybe libnice sources could help and some related RFC...